# get_post_type() in in_array doesn't work for some reason

Tags: functions, metabox, array, post-type

I am trying to create some function for metaboxes and some reason i can't get `get_post_type` to work in `in_array`.

Everything else seems to work in testing but in_array nope.

This is the function that i have

```
$metabox = array(
    'metabox_one' => array(
      'title' => 'First',
      'screen' => array( 'post' )
    ),
    'metabox_two' => array(
      'title' => 'Second',
      'screen' => array( 'post', 'page')
    )
 );
```

So for each of those keys in array i want to check `screen` value and if it's in that array to display metabox.

```
 function call_vivid_framework_metaboxClass() { 
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if( isset($metabox) ) {
        foreach ( $metabox as $key => $value ) {
            if ( in_array( $post_type, $value['screen'] )) { 
                new vivid_framework_metaboxClass( $key, $value );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'call_vivid_framework_metaboxClass' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'call_vivid_framework_metaboxClass' );
```

And this is when it fails and basically don't display any metabox as it doesn't exist in the array.

When i try to print `$value['screen']` i get an array

```
[0] => post,
[1] => page
```

When i try to print `$post_type` on a new page i get an `page` but still it fails `in_array`

When i try to manually set an array instead `$value['screen']` as:

```
$screen = array( 'post', 'page');
```

It fails again.

And when i try to manually set post type in `in_array` than it works as:

```
  in_array('page', $value['screen'])
```

It loads metabox within that `$value` array.

The only thing that comes to my min is that my function hook is fired before get_post_type() so it doesn't catch the value of post type.

For the class i used and example from WordPress codex page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Class

Any ideas or suggestion how to get it to work ?

Comment: `metabox_one` and `metabox_two` aren't valid array keys - they should be in quotes. Where is the `foreach` loop you describe? Is your call to `get_post_type()` returning something that's  not `false`? Is the constructor of `class vivid_framework_metaboxClass` actually coded to produce markup? What "function hook" are you suspecting of firing before `get_post_type()`?

Comment: As i said everything works if i don't use `in_array( $post_type, $value['screen'] )` combination. I already said `get_post_type()` returns 'page' the consturctor of class works good it shows and saves everything as it should. and metabox keys is just a typo here in post. foreach loop is activated inside function which is called by `add_action( 'load-post.php', 'call_vivid_framework_metaboxClass' );` I did made a workaround by using in_array in class constructor instead a function but i am still curious why it doesn't work inside function here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`add_meta_boxes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/) to add metaboxes.

This hook fires only the appropriate page and also pass as argumument the current post type, so you can use it instead retrieving it with `get_post_type()`.

Sample code:

```
function call_vivid_framework_metaboxClass( $post_type ) { 

    // if the metabox var is set outside the function, you should
    // declare it as global
    global $metabox;

    if( ! isset( $metabox ) || ! is_array( $metabox ) ) {
      return;
    }

    foreach ( $metabox as $key => $value ) {
      if (
        isset( $value['screen'] )
        && in_array( $post_type, $value['screen'], true )
      ) { 
         new vivid_framework_metaboxClass( $key, $value );
      }
   }
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'call_vivid_framework_metaboxClass' );
```

Note that I added a check for `isset( $value['screen'] )` because you should always check a variable is defined before to use it.

Comment: I thought this would work, but it's not. I guess i can't call `add_meta_boxes` when i have a class for metaboxes. I have updated my question so you can see what class vivid_framework_metaboxClass is firing.

Comment: There' no reason at all why you could not use `add_meta_boxes` hook from a class. It makes no difference. @AleksandarĐorđević